Need assistance running my scripts automatically after reboot
I'm not very skilled in PowerShell and I could really use some help with this. I've actually managed to complete most of what I need.
So I managed to cobble together 4 scripts that complete the process I wanted.
Script 1: changes a value in the registry (this is currently just a reg file. I will soon change it to a powershell script). Users run this by clicking on batch file 1
Script 2: restarts the PC (I will be able to just combine steps 1 and 2 when I eventually change the reg file to a powershell script) Users run this by clicking on batch file 2
Script 3: Leaves the domain and joins a workgroup called "Change", then reboots the pc. Users run this by clicking on batch file 3
Script 4: Joins the domain and changes the computer name, then reboots the pc. Users run this by clicking on batch file 4
So I've got all these parts working well. But right now users have to manually click these batch files to complete the various steps. I want to make it so that the users can click one file and have this script continuously proceed to each step, even after the reboots. I saw the idea of setting a task to automatically run a script and writing to a txt file and checking the state of this file after each reboot to determine which step to run. So I guess my question is how do I do that? I'll post the scripts starting from step 2 (since step 1 is still just a reg file).
Step 2:

Restart-Computer

Step 3:

$credential = Get-Credential


Remove-Computer -UnjoinDomainCredential $credential -WorkgroupName "Change" -PassThru -Verbose -Restart

Step 4:

$WSID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your workstation ID'


Add-Computer -ComputerName $WSID -DomainName Redacted -Restart


I guess there are several ways of doing this, but one way would be to add a task to the Task Scheduler (taskschd.msc) that is triggered when the user logs on.
See the example here; below is an altered version of it that executes a Powershell script:
$Sta = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument '-File "C:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1"'
$Stt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon
Register-ScheduledTask Task01 -Action $Sta -Trigger $Stt 

Since it only needs to execute once, you probably want your scheduled script (MyScript.ps1 in this example) to remove the Scheduled task again:
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task01"


Appreciate you. I figured this part out thankfully. But yes, this method does work!
